# Distance Matrix from table in R

Tags: r, euclidean-distance, distance-matrix

Good evening,

I need to solve a location problem in R and I'm stuck in one of the first steps.

From a .txt file I need to create a distance matrix using the euclidean method.

```
datos <- file.choose()
servidores <- read.table(datos)
servidores
```

From which I obtain the following information:
X50 shows the total number of servers.
x5 the number of hubs required.
x120 the total capacity.

The first column shows the distance of x.
The second column shows the distance of y.
The third column shows the requirements of the node.

```
   X50  X5 X120
1    2  62    3
2   80  25   14
3   36  88    1
4   57  23   14
5   33  17   19
6   76  43    2
7   77  85   14
8   94   6    6
9   89  11    7
10  59  72    6
11  39  82   10
12  87  24   18
13  44  76    3
14   2  83    6
15  19  43   20
16   5  27    4
17  58  72   14
18  14  50   11
19  43  18   19
20  87   7   15
21  11  56   15
22  31  16    4
23  51  94   13
24  55  13   13
25  84  57    5
26  12   2   16
27  53  33    3
28  53  10    7
29  33  32   14
30  69  67   17
31  43   5    3
32  10  75    3
33   8  26   12
34   3   1   14
35  96  22   20
36   6  48   13
37  59  22   10
38  66  69    9
39  22  50    6
40  75  21   18
41   4  81    7
42  41  97   20
43  92  34    9
44  12  64    1
45  60  84    8
46  35 100    5
47  38   2    1
48   9   9    7
49  54  59    9
50   1  58    2
```

I tried to use the `dist()` function:
`distance_matrix <-dist(servidores,method = "euclidean",diag = TRUE,upper = TRUE)` 
but since x and y are on different columns I am not sure what to do to get a 50x50 matrix with all the distances.

Anybody knows how could I create such matrix?.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `as.matrix(dist(servidores,method = "euclidean",diag = TRUE,upper = TRUE))`  ?

Comment: D'OH
Had I run these commands before I would had seen R wasn't just returning 20 rows :)
`> nrow(matriz_distancia)
[1] 50
> ncol(matriz_distancia)
[1] 50`